# how to find the domain of a function given the domain of 2 other functions

Tags: functions

> The function $v$ lies between $0<t<800$ (inclusive)
> the function $v_1$ lies between $0<t<400$ (inclusive). What will the function ($v_1-v)$ lie between?

p.s : yes it's on a velocity-time graph.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, sakura. What have you tried? See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance. In particular, please provide an idea of your thought process, aim for correct grammar, and typeset in MathJax if possible.

Comment: If you want to know the minimum of (v1-v), you take the minimal v1 and subtract maximal v. And you can make a simillar thought for the maximum.

Comment: Further comments: I think you are referring to domain, rather than range? Do you know anything about $v_1$ on $(400,800]$ - is it zero there? Otherwise the question is ill-posed.

Comment: im terribly sorry. yes, i meant the domain.

Comment: hume, i am sorry for the misunderstanding. i meant the domain (x) which in this case, is t. and not the range (y), in this case v.